# when i log in my prod env it crashesw with "500 Internal server error" in symfony2

Tags: symfony, authentication, production-environment

I'm working with Symfony2.3.4 and PHP5.6.3

This happens only when I AM LOGGED IN PROD ENV, while I'm not or when I'm in dev env(logged or not) nothing bad happens, I can go anywhere in my site(security is not implemented yet).

Has anyone run into this issue already? I really don't know what other info you'd need to help me, please feel free to yell back for extra info.

**routing.yml**

---

```
homepage:
    pattern: /homepage/
    defaults: { _controller: GCBundle:Default:homepage }

UserBundle:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /user/

GCBundle:
    resource: "@GCBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /gc/

ReportsBundle:
    resource: "@ReportsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /reports/
```

**routing_dev.yml**

---

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml

#AcmeDemoBundle routes (to be removed)

_acme_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

thanks

Comment: Clear the cache. Read your app/log/prod.log file.

Comment: Also check your PHP logs.

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié, that was so awesome, I had never thought about checking my prod.log, I read it there was the error, as clear as a TFT Super IPS+, :).+1 4u. BTW, do u happen to know a way I could get those errors to be output in the browser just like in dev env, so I don't need to check the prod.log

Comment: @Matteo'Ingannatore'G. I didn't get to check the PHP logs because I fixed it following the first comment, but for future reference, where can I find these?

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría it is **intended** that prod env hides errors. Since it's in production, you don't want to disclose too much. But if you really want, you can enable the debug by changing the code in app.php to `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` .